# Build error when creating an Android React Native Module with dependencies

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to figure out the best solution to handle this error with Android Studio, Gradle and React Native.

I have followed the [Native Modules NPM Package Setup](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup) to create a React Native Module both for iOS and Android.

Once executed the following command, the CLI generates on my behalf a template contain an example application and `react-native-awesome-module` RN Module.

`npx create-react-native-library@latest react-native-awesome-module`

Everything goes smooth.

Since `react-native-awesome-module` needs to wrap a custom dependency available in my maven repository, e.g. `custom-dependency`, within the `build.gradle (Module :react-native-awesome-module)` I've added both the repository and the implementation sections used to resolve the dependency itself.

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
  maven { // <-- This block here
    credentials {
      username = "USERNAME"
      password = "PASSWORD"
    }
    setUrl("MAVEN_URL")
  }
}

dependencies {
  // For < 0.71, this will be from the local maven repo
  // For > 0.71, this will be replaced by `com.facebook.react:react-android:$version` by react gradle plugin
  //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  implementation "it.mycompany.custom-dependency:1.0.0" // <-- This line here
}
```

If I try to build the example application, I receive the following error.

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find it.mycompany.custom-dependency:1.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/PATH_TO_POM.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/PATH_TO_POM.pom
       - file:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/example/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/PATH_TO_POM.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/PATH_TO_POM.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/PATH_TO_POM.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-awesome-module
```

The only solution to make it works is to add both repositories and dependencies also in the `build.gradle (Module :app)`, i.e. the ones labeled with `// <-- Comment`.

Do you have any suggestion on why this happens?

Thanks,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

This means that Gradle cannot find the dependency `it.mycompany.custom-dependency:1.0.0` in any repositories it is configured to search.

Verify these steps:

Make sure that the dependency is available in a repository that Gradle is configured to search. You can check this by looking at the `GRADLE_REPOSITORIES` environment variable.

If the dependency is available in a `repository`, but Gradle does not have permission to access it, you can try changing the `GRADLE_USER_AGENT` environment variable

If the dependency is available in a repository, but it is not the correct version, you can try changing the dependency version in the `build.gradle` file

If the dependency is available in a repository, but it is not compatible with the project, you can try changing the project dependencies in the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you can see from my explanation, I'm wondering why configuring the dependency in the build.gradle of the app, makes the build working. Any clue on that?